# How to draw stacked and normal series in one TeeChart for HTML5?

Tags: javascript, teechart

Hi I'm using the TeeChart for HTML5 and would like to know how to draw stacked and normal series in a one chart. I need to have two series stacked and third one unstacked (normal). I tried to set the *stacked* property for particular series. But it it doesn't work for me - all series are stacked...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/v2014.07.31.1.7/src/teechart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/v2014.07.31.1.7/src/teechart-extras.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var Chart1;

    function draw() {
      Chart1 = new Tee.Chart("canvas");
      Chart1.addSeries(new Tee.Line([1, 2, 3]));
      Chart1.addSeries(new Tee.Line([1, 2, 3]));
      Chart1.addSeries(new Tee.Line([4, 4, 4]));

      Chart1.axes.left.title.text = "Y";

      Chart1.title.text = "Stacked Lines";
      Chart1.title.format.font.style = "18px Verdana";

      Chart1.series.items[0].stacked = true;
      Chart1.series.items[1].stacked = true;
      Chart1.series.items[2].stacked = false;

      Chart1.draw();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="draw()">

  <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400">
    This browser does not seem to support HTML5 Canvas.
  </canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In other TeeChart versions, like in TeeChart VCL, you have the option to set Stack Groups.

I've added this feature to the public tracker for TeeChart HTML/Javascript:
http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=1159